# Is it faulty RAM or CPU

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod, cpu-usage, memtest

I stream on twitch and recently I started getting BSoD. I though I had virus or something so I reinstalled windows. That didnt work...
Next I opened my task bar and checked for any high usage programs, the only programs I had opened were google with 6 tabs opened on it. I saw that sometimes my google chrome would use between 75 and 85% of my CPU. After that I started to look for answers and somehow I landed on memtests86...
So I was like ok why not im going to test every component in my pc starting from ram. I have 2×8gb ram and I take one of them out and I boot the program. What I saw that I had more than 8000 errors in the first 2 passes all of them starting from test 3 going up to test 9. I dont know anymore and pls help me understand which component I should change, I guess its ram but just to be 110% sure I want to hear it from someone that has more experience with those things.
Sorry for the long message :(
And thank you for your help:)

Comment: do you get the same results with the other stick of RAM?

Comment: The other ram stick only gives me 500+ errors. ( the first one that I was testing had 10k errors and it shut itself because of that).

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the bottom line: That's bad. If memtest gives *any* errors, something is seriously broken. If both RAM modules give errors, it's either that both of them are broken or, as you suspect, the CPU or the main board. It's very hard to reliably tell whether it's the CPU or the mainboard, because they're linked very closely to each other. Also, if you need to buy a new board or CPU, you'll often have to replace both of them anyway, as you might at the same time upgrade to a more recent model with a different socket.

Comment: I have ordered new ram, and I will run the program and hope that the ram was the problem.

Comment: Also what would you recommend me to do, so that never happens again?

Comment: @MartinMollov - You cannot prevent random hardware failures.  Electronics fail for all sorts of reasons.  Unless you were running around in fuzzy socks, on carpet, and touching the motherboard, CPU, memory modules without being grounded there wasn't anything you could have done to prevent any failure that happened.